# SUM counts from parent and child

Tags: mysql

With this **SQL-query**, I am able to obtain the `count(*)` of items in subcategory, but I want to be able to `SUM` total items, from both main (*parent*) category and subcategory (*child*), how can this be achieved?

```
SELECT parent.name,
COUNT(sub.item_id) AS total
FROM categories parent
LEFT JOIN subcategories child ON parent.category_id = child.category_id
LEFT JOIN item_subcategory sub ON child.subcategory_id = sub.subcategory_id
LEFT JOIN items i ON sub.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY parent.name;
```

[image]

**EDIT:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec5b8/1

Note, I am using the latest MySQL on my PC, but the one supported there is 5.6 at highest, for some reason I keep getting syntax error.

---

**EDIT2:** This QUERY currently COUNTs ITEMS in subcategories, is IT possible to within the same query count for items in main categories and then SUM these two counts.

Comment: Could you please add expected result?

Comment: I added a sqlfiddle now.

Comment: @Akina, please see now. I didn't know. Thanks for letting me know,

Comment: I see structures. But I do NOT see any sample data (INSERT INTO statements)... add please, 2-3 records per table is enough.

Comment: @Akina, FIXED! What you requested.

Comment: Well. Your query now gives 2 records with 2 fields. Please add desured result for that data (one more field? one more record?).

Comment: It currently only counts from the `subcategory` and ignores `categories`, if you see **Pepsi** is inserted under category **Pepsi**, while **Pepsi MAX** is under **Pepsi/Zero**,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
SELECT name, COUNT(item_id) 
FROM ( SELECT c.name, i.item_id
       FROM categories c
       LEFT JOIN item_category ic ON ic.category_id = c.category_id
       LEFT JOIN items i ON ic.item_id = i.item_id

     UNION ALL

       SELECT c.name, i.item_id
       FROM categories c
       LEFT JOIN subcategories sc ON sc.category_id = c.category_id
       LEFT JOIN item_subcategory isc ON isc.subcategory_id = sc.subcategory_id
       LEFT JOIN items i ON isc.item_id = i.item_id
     ) total
GROUP BY name /* WITH ROLLUP */
;
```

or

```sql
SELECT name, SUM(cnt)
FROM ( SELECT c.name, COUNT(i.item_id) cnt
       FROM categories c
       LEFT JOIN item_category ic ON ic.category_id = c.category_id
       LEFT JOIN items i ON ic.item_id = i.item_id
       GROUP BY c.name

     UNION ALL

       SELECT c.name, COUNT(i.item_id)
       FROM categories c
       LEFT JOIN subcategories sc ON sc.category_id = c.category_id
       LEFT JOIN item_subcategory isc ON isc.subcategory_id = sc.subcategory_id
       LEFT JOIN items i ON isc.item_id = i.item_id
       GROUP BY c.name
     ) total
GROUP BY name /* WITH ROLLUP */
;
```

Comment: This is what I had anticipated. I was thinking about `UNION` all the time. But, is this efficient? Thanks.

Comment: Akina, is this really the best way of doing this? Thx.

Comment: @ErikEriksson You may group and count in separate subqueries of UNION then sum counts in outer query. Variant added.